# How can I ignore files/directories when building debian packages?

Tags: linux, debian, svn, dpkg

I have made some debian packages to ease deployment of configurations on new servers and want to put them in SVN source control. The problem is that SVN creates a .svn directory for each subdirectory in the source tree, so I can't build packages on the source tree 'dpkg-deb --build ' because the '.svn' directories will be included in the resulting package. So far when I want to build a package I have to export the directory to a different place and build from there.

Is there a quick way to making 'dpkg-deb --build' ignore the .svn directories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that you should not be building a debian package with `dpkg-deb --build` in the first place. If you use `dpkg-buildpackage` instead, you won't have to worry about .svn directories being included in your package.

See: http://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/12/17/do-not-build-a-debian-package-with-dpkg-b/

There may be a better method, but here's one I haven't thoroughly tested:

Use `dh_make` to create a skeleton debian package. Put your files in the directory above the `debian` directory.

edit the resulting `dirs` file, and put the paths you are going to move files into, eg:

```
/opt/mypackage
/usr/local/bin
```

Then in your `rules` file, remove the $(MAKE) code and set your install: build section to something like this:

```
install: build
  dh_testdir
  dh_testroot
  dh_clean -k 
  dh_installdirs

  # Copy files into staging area
  rsync --exclude .svn -a mypackage/ debian/tmp/opt/mypackage/
```

Comment: Note: this is "old school" debhelper. Since debhelper has migrated to `dh $@` and the new targets like `override_dh_auto_build-indep`

Comment: @FranklinPiat is correct

Comment: That blog post you linked to basically says, "don't use `dpkg -b`, instead spend the next 4 hours studying https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/" Where's the helloworld version?

Answer (score 11):

To exclude files to be put in the source Debian package, you should create the file:

```
debian/source/options
```

and enter the options you want to pass to dpkg-source, in your case:

```
tar-ignore = ".svn/"
```

See the man page for dpkg-source.

Comment: This is slightly wrong. Using `".svn/*"` the ".svn" folder is going to be included, still. You should just use `".svn"`. Also if you need to exclude multiple folders (say "tmp" as well) write one line per exclusion.

Comment: Note that you can have multiple `tar-ignore` lines in the `options` file if you want to ignore multiple files/folders

Answer (score 5):

It's worth documenting here that if you're going to use `dpkg-buildpackage` that it has a `-i` switch to ignore things.  i.e., use `-i .svn` to ignore the .svn directory.